# Hosting WCF on IIS5/6

Tags: wcf, iis

I have developed a Web service using WCF Service Application. This service application is a part of multiple projects. we have data access , services(business logic) , testing(to test class)  and WCF Service application.Where WCF Service application is just like an infterface and all the request are sent to the services project. so all the projects communicate with each other. I am new to hosting WCF application. Now to host this on IIS do i have to put the whole project in the IIS virtual directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the WCF Service project in Visual Studio and choose Publish.

Comment: But with asp.net web application, we usually put the files manually in IIS virtual directory

Comment: @Pinu: I suggest you use Publish for ASP.NET applications as well. It knows what files need to be there and knows how to put them there.

Comment: Hey John thank ,I tried publish and it worked for me , it built all my class library in to a dll :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually copy the needed files or setup a script or other automated process to do it for you. Perhaps a Visual Studio post build event. I create my WCF services in their own website project under my solution. Then when it is time to deploy/update the production site, I copy the *.svc file(s) and the *.dll file(s) in the bin directory to the production folders. I keep a seperated web.config for my production and development environments.